# как задать значение по умолчанию для Radiobutton Tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Есть два Radiobutton

```
the_radiobutton_boy = Radiobutton(root, text='Boy', variable=r, value=1)

the_radiobutton_girl = Radiobutton(root, text='Girl', variable=r, value=2)
```

нужно что бы один из них был выбран по умолчанию.

Есть ли такой метод для Radiobutton?

Если нет, то как лучше это реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы можете установить значение для объекта переменной `r` сразу после его определения

```
r = tk.IntVar()
r.set(1)
```

и виджеты отобразят текущее состояние.

Comment: Спасибо! Помогло!)