# Как используя add_radiobutton() для каскада в Menu() из Tkinter установить галочку по умолчанию напротив одного из значений?

Tags: python, tkinter, menu, radiobutton

Когда запускается программа с размерами по умолчанию, например 10х10, в подменю size галочка уже должна стоять напротив строки `10х10`. Пробовал [**ответ отсюда**](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/767060/%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-radiobutton-tkinter), но тогда изначально галочки все равно нет, а если её поставить, то она уже не снимается. Нужно изначально указать один из вариантов, а дальше чтобы можно было выбирать любой вариант

```
from tkinter import Tk, Menu

root = Tk()
menubar = Menu(root)
size = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
size.add_radiobutton(label='5x5')
size.add_radiobutton(label='10x10')  # <- Нужно чтобы тут сразу стояла галочка при запуске.
                                     # А при выборе другого варианта она снималась, 
                                     # как и в данном примере
size.add_radiobutton(label='15x15')
menubar.add_cascade(label='Size', menu=size)
root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51544683/python-tkinter-how-to-set-the-default-value-of-a-radiobutton

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: @S.Nick изменил пример, теперь вроде понятнее

Comment: @Александр от этого галочка при запуске не появится. а если её самому поставить, то уже не снимется. и то и то плохо. либо я до конца не понял как это применить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В англоязычной версии сайта [подсказали](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75266437/how-to-use-add-radiobutton-to-cascade-in-menu-from-tkinter-to-set-a-default/75269197#75269197) как правильно использовать `IntVar` со значением по умолчанию, `variable` и `value`. В реальности я это всё в методе класса применял, поэтому чтобы заработало пришлось `self.size_var` использовать. В остальном способ идеально решил проблему

```
from tkinter import Tk, Menu, IntVar

root = Tk()
menubar = Menu(root)
size = Menu(tearoff=0)
size_var = IntVar(value=10)
size.add_radiobutton(label='5x5', variable=size_var)
size.add_radiobutton(label='10x10', variable=size_var, value=10)
size.add_radiobutton(label='15x15', variable=size_var)

menubar.add_cascade(label='Size', menu=size)
root.config(menu=menubar)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Вот ваша цитата "поэтому чтобы заработало пришлось self.size_var использовать", а где у вас это в примере?

Comment: @Александр я имел ввиду, что если использовать этот код в методе класса, то он работать не будет. Но если добавить `self`, то всё заработает. Из-за этого не сразу разобрался, вдруг кому-то этот момент тоже будет не понятен. Само по себе это не имеет отношение к примеру, без классов и мой пример, и исправленный вариант отлично работают и происходи то, что меня и интересовало изначально. Это же ответ на мой собственный вопрос